# How to create click event for specific link in a jQuery listview.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a function that starts when you click on a specific link in a listview. 
The issue is that event doesn't seem to fire when you click the link. The list is created dynamically. I'm not sure if that causes an issue.

```
    <label for="listviewForLastTenCalls">Last Ten Calls:</label>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="listviewForLastTenCalls">
    </ul>
<script>
   $('#listviewForLastTenCalls li').click(function(){
        //alert('click event handler fired');
</script>
```

Comment: some more HTML please

Comment: Ya, post relevant HTML code, there is no LI in your actual code...

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#listviewForLastTenCalls li', function () {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/msbVk/)

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listviewForLastTenCalls">
  <!-- items dynamically generated -->
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#listviewForLastTenCalls li a', function () {
 // code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help omar that works. I forgot that the event handler would try to latch on an li that didn't exist until at document load.

Comment: @Matt you're welcome, please check the demo for further details :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are adding the click listener after you have created the list. When you first create the listener there is nothing for it to listen to. You need to add the on click event after you add the `<li>`

Comment: or better, using delegation

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#listviewForLastTenCalls li a').click( function () {
 // code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not your fully markup,...

```
  <label for="listviewForLastTenCalls">Last Ten Calls:</label>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="listviewForLastTenCalls">
    </ul>

<script>
   $('#listviewForLastTenCalls li').click(function(){
        //alert('click event handler fired');
   }); //<--
</script>
```

And if the list is creadted dynamically, you have to attach the event, after list was created...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements.

```
    $('"#listviewForLastTenCalls"').on("click",'li' ,function(){
       alert('triggered');
    });
```

And why on() works ??

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $("#listviewForLastTenCalls li").on('click', function() { alert('clicked');  });
});
```