# add listener to js created element. jquery ON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to attach a listener to an element created via js dom manipulation. I thought that this is what jquery ON was for, but the below example is not working.

It works with the initial element, but not with any that are added via JS. The added elements have the correct class name.

```
<div id = "tag_options">
    <div class = 'tag_option'>test</div>
</div>


function greet(event) { alert("Hello "); }
$("[class='tag_option']").on("click", {}, greet);
```

Comment: The docs describe how to use `.on()` in order to work with elements to be added in the future. You may want to start there. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: when the second argument of $.on is not a selector => a direct event handler, when the second argument of $.on is a selector, the event is delegated event. In your code, you're declaring a direct event handler. That's why it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create click event for specific link in a jQuery listview.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301307/how-to-create-click-event-for-specific-link-in-a-jquery-listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function greet(event) { alert("Hello "); }

$("#tag_options").on("click", ".tag_option", greet);
```

Comment: from other responses: $("#tag_options") needs to be static, else use $(document.body) or other static ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation, e.g:

```
$(document.body).on("click","[class='tag_option']", greet);
```

Comment: Using `[class='tag_option']` will be slow when comparing with `.tag_option`.

Comment: Closest parent would be better, if that's the element with tag_options as it's id then then Aguardientico's answer would be slightly better as it wouldn't check for delegation when you click outide of the tag_options element.

Comment: @user984003: roasted should have explained that you should bind the handler to the nearest ancestor that encompasses the `tag_option` elements.

Comment: @CrazyTrain ya i could but as OP give as little description as possible, i do the same

Comment: @HMR ya sure, but what is the closest static container following OP question? Is #tag_options static or not, who knows?!

Comment: @Crazy Train: yes, that will improve performance in case the OP does not need to monitor all `.tag_option`. But the OP gives so little information, so i think this answer is still good.

Comment: @roasted That's why I mention if that's the closest (forgot static) parent. We don't know but the OP and future visitors will.

Comment: @KhanhTO, roasted: Consider that other people read the answers here.

Comment: @CrazyTrain there are thousand duplicate of this kind of question and many duplicates are more descriptive as this one. But for sure you are right ;)