# JQuery - Use selectors on generated content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I'm having problems selecting elements with jquery selectors on content generated with javascript.

For the generation I use the following function:

```
var articles = [
    {
        img: { src: this.base_url + 'assets/img/frontend/placeholder.png', alt: 'Image Description' },
        title : 'Title Here',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adispiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet ' + 
              'dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.'
    },
    {
        img: { src: this.base_url + 'assets/img/frontend/placeholder.png', alt: 'Image Description' },
        title : 'Title Here',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adispiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet ' + 
              'dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.'
    },
    {
        img: { src: this.base_url + 'assets/img/frontend/placeholder.png', alt: 'Image Description' },
        title : 'Title Here',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adispiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet ' + 
              'dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.'
    }
];

var template = Handlebars.compile( $( '#picture-above-text' ).html() );
$( 'div.editor-wrapper' ).append( template( articles ) );
```

This inserts the following html in the page :

```
<div class="row insumo-editor-module" style="display: none;">
    {{#each this}}
        <article class="span4" article-tile>
            <figure>
                <div class="figure-holder">
                    <img src="{{img.src}}" alt="{{img.alt}}">
                    <span class="figure-indicator"></span>
                </div>
                <figcaption>
                    <div class="editable"><h4>{{title}} <i class="icon-edit"></i></h4></div>
                    <div class="editable"><p>{{text}} <i class="icon-edit"></i></p></div>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Up to this point there are no problems. However when I use

```
$( 'i.icon-edit' ).on( 'click', function() {
    alert( 'editing' );
});
```

nothing is happening. Does anyone know why this is happening? I guess it's because the icon wasn't on the page when the DOM was first generated. Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery .on() not working on dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-not-working-on-dynamic-content)

Comment: try to attach `click` after this line: `$( 'div.editor-wrapper' ).append( template( articles ) );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create click event for specific link in a jQuery listview.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301307/how-to-create-click-event-for-specific-link-in-a-jquery-listview)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `icon-edit` is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', 'i.icon-edit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( 'editing' ); 
});
```

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. It works perfectly.
@dystroy: thank you, sorry I didn't find the article you linked to, I looked before asking but didn't find that article

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery delegate.
[Klik link](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)