# How to specify dynamic element in javascript on() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have approximately such structure:

```
<div class='container'>
 <div class='element' data-id='1'></div>
 <div class='element' data-id='2'></div>
 <div class='element' data-id='2'></div>
</div>
```

Where `.element`s' are rendered dynamically.

So I wrote handler for these elements:

```
jQuery('.container').on('click', '.element', function () { //code })
```

But I need to do something with element, which was clicked.

How could I get clicked element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create click event for specific link in a jQuery listview.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301307/how-to-create-click-event-for-specific-link-in-a-jquery-listview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clicked element will be `this` in your event handler function.

```
jQuery('.container').on('click', '.element', function () { 
    // use "this" or "jQuery(this)", depending on your needs
})
```

Note that `this` will point to a DOM element, in your case a `<div>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! So simple and evident answer and so helpful for me! Thanks for editing codestyle too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something with the target of the event.

Something like :

```
jQuery('.container').on('click', '.element', function (event) { 
    var clickedelement = $(event.target);
    //code 
})
```

Comment: Sorry, re-reading OP question, i think here effectively event.target is what OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
 <div class='element' data-id='1'/>
 <div class='element' data-id='2'/>
 <div class='element' data-id='2'/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('.container').on('click', '.element', function () {
    $clickedElement = $(this);
    $data-id = $clickedElement.attr('data-id');
  });
});
```