# Jquery, "on" method is not binding properly in dynamically elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

After reading a bunch of solutions to my problem I couldn't find an answer, so I did mine.

I'm adding html code when a button is clicked like this:

```
$(".button").on('click',function(){
    var p = $(this).parent(); 
    var data =  //  HTML CODE
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>&nbsp;</td>'+
    '<td><br /><textarea name="taDescripcion" class="txtArea mark">Write here</textarea></td>'+
    '<td>&nbsp;</td>'+
  '</tr>'+
  '<tr>'+
    '<td>&nbsp;</td>'+
    '<td><br /><input disabled="disabled" class="button" type="button" value="Send" /> |' +
    '<span class="linkUnderL">Cancel</span></td>' +
   ' <td>&nbsp;</td>'+
  '</tr>';
    $(p).append(data);
});
```

The text area input have a class (`txtArea`), this class already have an event attached, created in the `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(".txtArea").on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(".button").attr('disabled',true); 
        }
        else $(".button").attr('disabled',false);   
    });
```

For any reason text area event is not working, the class is added correctly, styles works fine. I've tried using `.delegate()` and putting the event inside `$(function(){ ..code.. });` it didn't work

What am I doing wrong? ... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to pass a selector to `.on()` for delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: You are binding a dynamic event to a dynamically added element. You have to bind the event to a static element (preferably the closest existing element), which must exist in the DOM at the time of the binding....`$("closest existing element").on('keyup', .txtArea', function (e) { ... });`

Comment: Ohh thats my problem the element doesn't exist until is added, so the event is never attached to it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can anyone tell me why de downvote ?

Comment: `$(document).on('keyup', '.txtArea', function` as `<textarea>` is also dynamic. so you also can use `$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea.txtArea', function`

Comment: There is this great article in the learning center: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create click event for specific link in a jQuery listview.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301307/how-to-create-click-event-for-specific-link-in-a-jquery-listview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the parent in the original selector if you want to bind the event to dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...
```

This should apply it to all textarea's within the document.

It's also worth point out that, unless you really do need to apply it to ALL text areas across the entire document, you shouldn't use `$(document)` as the initial selector but rather as narrow a scope/parent as possible.  That is, if only textareas within `<div id="parent"` are to have this rule applied, then you should write

```
$('#parent').on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...
```

Comment: Of course this will, but its also the same as using `.live` which they moved to .on for performance.

Comment: @JamieHutber what does `.live` have to do with this question/answer?  Yes, it is the same, but the current recommendation is to use `.on`.

Comment: Do you understand the benefits of using `.on` over `.live`? To me you seem to have missed the entire purpose of using `.on`. I'm confident you do know...

Comment: I would like to know too, hehehe 
This worked, thanks for your help

Comment: removed it because i may have been a little extreme :p But i'm still maintaining that $(document) is always a bad idea when using `.on`

Comment: @JamieHutber The purposes are beyond the point, [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) clearly states that _As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers._

Comment: @JamieHutber Oh, that's what you're talking about!.. Of course using $(document) is extreme.  That's why I said in my text that it needs _to specify the parent_.  $(document) in my code was simply an example - for a lack of any other reference available in the original question.

Comment: come on @AleksG you're completely missing the point on why they deprecated it. More to the point, not once have I suggest he used it. Is English your native tongue? If its not that my apologies.  Maybe go over what I've written.

Comment: @Mollo please see the note I added to my answer

Comment: @JamieHutber Please see the note I added to my answer.

Comment: I just read it ... Bad teaching, why ? I learned what I was doing wrong. In order to attach an event to an element, this must exist first in the DOM and adding .on to document, is just for extreme cases

Answer (score 1):

Set `on` on the document rather than the text area class:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...});
```

You need to have the event set on something that is already in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but the `.on` function needs to be bound on an element that is available on pageload.

In short, you need to make sure that the binding element is there from page load.

```
$("avaliableFromTheStart").on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){
```

I believe this might help.

**EDIT**

The reason `$(document).on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...` is a bad idea and is exactly the same as using the now decrepitude `.live` is that putting the `.on` on the `document` means that when this element is clicked it will have to bubble all the up until it finds the top level `document`. A very bad idea if you can avoid it.

The only time this will make sense is if you are building a ajax application.

Comment: Hmm, the element (text area) doesn't exist until is added

Comment: ok, then keep going up in the elements until you have one that is available. try a very generic `div` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(".txtArea").on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...});`

To `$(document).on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...});`

Or, to a selector parent of .txtArea, and delegates correctly ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might try to attach the event to the document.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.txtArea', function(e) {
        if($(e.target).val() == ""){
            $(".button").attr('disabled',true); 
        }
        else $(".button").attr('disabled',false);   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$(".txtArea").on('keyup','.txtArea',function(){...});
```

To:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.txtArea', function(){...});
```

Comment: ohh sorry ... i saw that this is for i will update. I didn't read your question right i tought that you are executing this code after you have appended the elements

Answer (score 0):

You're still attaching events to dynamic elements.

Instead of

`$(".button").on('click', function(){ });`

Attach the event to an element that isn't dynamic, like `document` or a more immediate parent of the element (maybe whatever `var p = $(this).parent();` selects):

`$(document).on('click', '.button', function(){ });`